# Proximity calculation on 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, proximity

I am trying to write a simple map system for a game. It uses 2D vector to store area objects (map chunks) and now I want to do 3x3 areas proximity. Areas are stored in:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Area>>
```

My currently proximity check uses:

```
bool area_exist;
if (x - 1 < 0 || y + 1 > max_y)
    area_exist = true;
else
    area_exist = false;
if (area_exist)
    Area & p_area_right_top = areas[x - 1][y + 1];
if (x - 1 < 0)
    area_exist = true;
else
    area_exist = false;
if (area_exist)
    Area& p_area_top = areas[x - 1][y];...
```

In that option I must check first for the existence of the area.

Is there another way to receive 3x3 proximity objects ?

Comment: One decent "trick" is to use two nested for loops like: `for (int dx = -1, dx <= 1; dx++) { for (int dy = -1; dy<=1; dy++) { if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) DO_STUFF_WITH(x+dx,y+dy)} }`